# ksplashqml crashed

Tags: kubuntu, crash

Not sure what to even ask. This is Kubuntu 19.10. KDE appears to continue working. The crash happens maybe 25% of the time, always on first login. Rebooting generally shows no problem. It's been going on for a month or two.

```
    Application: ksplashqml (ksplashqml), signal: Aborted
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
futex_wait_cancelable (private=<optimized out>, expected=0, futex_word=0x55b31a0a9ae4) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:80
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7fa05c2cf840 (LWP 2065))]

Thread 7 (Thread 0x7fa04693b700 (LWP 2176)):
#0  __lll_lock_wait (futex=futex@entry=0x7fa053ff0960, private=0) at lowlevellock.c:52
#1  0x00007fa05fa2e1f1 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x7fa053ff0960) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:115
#2  0x00007fa0530e6d7c in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.440.59
#3  0x00007fa0531ebb9d in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.440.59
#4  0x00007fa0532a0500 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.440.59
#5  0x00007fa052e576eb in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.440.59
#6  0x00007fa0615e50fb in QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::renderMergedBatch(QSGBatchRenderer::Batch const*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#7  0x00007fa0615e6275 in QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::renderBatches() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#8  0x00007fa0615eb8e4 in QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::render() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#9  0x00007fa0615dc420 in QSGRenderer::renderScene(QSGBindable const&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#10 0x00007fa0615dc8e3 in QSGRenderer::renderScene(unsigned int) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#11 0x00007fa061619a34 in QSGDefaultRenderContext::renderNextFrame(QSGRenderer*, unsigned int) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#12 0x00007fa06167ecf0 in QQuickWindowPrivate::renderSceneGraph(QSize const&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#13 0x00007fa061625c68 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#14 0x00007fa0616299d8 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#15 0x00007fa060869c92 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#16 0x00007fa05fa2b669 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:479
#17 0x00007fa0604ee323 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 6 (Thread 0x7fa0475eb700 (LWP 2146)):
#0  __lll_lock_wait_private (futex=0x7fa0605b6b80 <main_arena>) at ./lowlevellock.c:35
#1  0x00007fa06046626a in _int_free (av=0x7fa0605b6b80 <main_arena>, p=0x55b31a0c9a60, have_lock=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4302
#2  0x00007fa060415c53 in __run_exit_handlers (status=1, listp=0x7fa0605b6718 <__exit_funcs>, run_list_atexit=run_list_atexit@entry=true, run_dtors=run_dtors@entry=true) at exit.c:124
#3  0x00007fa060415d60 in __GI_exit (status=<optimized out>) at exit.c:139
#4  0x00007fa05f8d6ef3 in _XDefaultIOError () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#5  0x00007fa05bc1b7be in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#6  0x00007fa05f8d71a2 in _XIOError () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#7  0x00007fa05f8d516c in _XReply () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#8  0x00007fa0596b4fba in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.0
#9  0x00007fa05968dc95 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.0
#10 0x00007fa0531732a0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.440.59
#11 0x00007fa0531de820 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.440.59
#12 0x00007fa0531e7e21 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.440.59
#13 0x00007fa0531ebea2 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.440.59
#14 0x00007fa0532a0500 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.440.59
#15 0x00007fa052e576eb in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.440.59
#16 0x00007fa0615e50fb in QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::renderMergedBatch(QSGBatchRenderer::Batch const*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#17 0x00007fa0615e6275 in QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::renderBatches() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#18 0x00007fa0615eb8e4 in QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::render() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#19 0x00007fa0615dc420 in QSGRenderer::renderScene(QSGBindable const&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#20 0x00007fa0615dc8e3 in QSGRenderer::renderScene(unsigned int) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#21 0x00007fa061619a34 in QSGDefaultRenderContext::renderNextFrame(QSGRenderer*, unsigned int) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#22 0x00007fa06167ecf0 in QQuickWindowPrivate::renderSceneGraph(QSize const&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#23 0x00007fa061625c68 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#24 0x00007fa0616299d8 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#25 0x00007fa060869c92 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#26 0x00007fa05fa2b669 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:479
#27 0x00007fa0604ee323 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 5 (Thread 0x7fa047fff700 (LWP 2092)):
[KCrash Handler]
#6  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#7  0x00007fa0603f1899 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#8  0x00007fa06045c38e in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7fa0605853a5 "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#9  0x00007fa0604644dc in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7fa0605870a0 "double free or corruption (out)") at malloc.c:5332
#10 0x00007fa060466170 in _int_free (av=0x7fa0605b6b80 <main_arena>, p=0x7fa03c179c80, have_lock=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4314
#11 0x00007fa0611ad36a in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#12 0x00007fa0611ac2b4 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#13 0x00007fa06117d57d in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#14 0x00007fa06117dc0e in QOpenGLShaderProgram::link() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#15 0x00007fa06161a238 in QSGDefaultRenderContext::compileShader(QSGMaterialShader*, QSGMaterial*, char const*, char const*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#16 0x00007fa0615e44d4 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#17 0x00007fa0615e4ed4 in QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::renderMergedBatch(QSGBatchRenderer::Batch const*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#18 0x00007fa0615e6275 in QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::renderBatches() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#19 0x00007fa0615eb8e4 in QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::render() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#20 0x00007fa0615dc420 in QSGRenderer::renderScene(QSGBindable const&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#21 0x00007fa0615dc8e3 in QSGRenderer::renderScene(unsigned int) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#22 0x00007fa061619a34 in QSGDefaultRenderContext::renderNextFrame(QSGRenderer*, unsigned int) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#23 0x00007fa06167ecf0 in QQuickWindowPrivate::renderSceneGraph(QSize const&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#24 0x00007fa061625c68 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#25 0x00007fa0616299d8 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#26 0x00007fa060869c92 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#27 0x00007fa05fa2b669 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:479
#28 0x00007fa0604ee323 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 4 (Thread 0x7fa058f5f700 (LWP 2083)):
#0  0x00007fa0604e1c2f in __GI___poll (fds=0x7fa0480025e0, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007fa05e9adaae in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007fa05e9adbe3 in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007fa060a88653 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x00007fa060a2f5cb in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007fa060868a45 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007fa060225319 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#7  0x00007fa060869c92 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007fa05fa2b669 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:479
#9  0x00007fa0604ee323 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7fa05a179700 (LWP 2072)):
#0  0x00007fa0604e1c2f in __GI___poll (fds=0x7fa04c0029e0, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007fa05e9adaae in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007fa05e9adbe3 in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007fa060a88653 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x00007fa060a2f5cb in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007fa060868a45 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007fa06133eefa in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#7  0x00007fa060869c92 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007fa05fa2b669 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:479
#9  0x00007fa0604ee323 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7fa05b452700 (LWP 2070)):
#0  0x00007fa0604e1c2f in __GI___poll (fds=0x7fa05b451c68, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007fa05f877917 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#2  0x00007fa05f87953a in xcb_wait_for_event () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#3  0x00007fa05bc1a288 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#4  0x00007fa060869c92 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007fa05fa2b669 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:479
#6  0x00007fa0604ee323 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fa05c2cf840 (LWP 2065)):
#0  futex_wait_cancelable (private=<optimized out>, expected=0, futex_word=0x55b31a0a9ae4) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:80
#1  __pthread_cond_wait_common (abstime=0x0, clockid=0, mutex=0x55b31a0a9a90, cond=0x55b31a0a9ab8) at pthread_cond_wait.c:508
#2  __pthread_cond_wait (cond=0x55b31a0a9ab8, mutex=0x55b31a0a9a90) at pthread_cond_wait.c:638
#3  0x00007fa06086fdbf in QWaitCondition::wait(QMutex*, QDeadlineTimer) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x00007fa06086feb1 in QWaitCondition::wait(QMutex*, unsigned long) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007fa061627d87 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#6  0x00007fa061628952 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#7  0x00007fa06168a726 in QQuickWindow::event(QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#8  0x00007fa060a30a2a in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007fa060e09ae4 in QPlatformWindow::windowEvent(QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#10 0x00007fa060e14b17 in QGuiApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#11 0x00007fa060a30a2a in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#12 0x00007fa060a87990 in QTimerInfoList::activateTimers() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0x00007fa060a8826c in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#14 0x00007fa05e9ad8bd in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#15 0x00007fa05e9adb40 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#16 0x00007fa05e9adbe3 in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#17 0x00007fa060a88635 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#18 0x00007fa060a2f5cb in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#19 0x00007fa060a37336 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#20 0x000055b31863002b in ?? ()
#21 0x00007fa0603f31e3 in __libc_start_main (main=0x55b31862fe70, argc=3, argv=0x7ffc684b6238, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffc684b6228) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#22 0x000055b31863009e in _start ()
[Inferior 1 (process 2065) detached]
```

Comment: Do you have crash report for this applications in `/var/crash` folder? Did you send it to developers/launchpad with apport?

Comment: There is a crash report from about a week ago. Nothing from yesterday's crash. I attempted to run apport-bug and let it collect information but it keeps giving me a dialog box that just says 'text' and doesn't appear to do anything so I killed it. I'll do some investigating as to how to better run apport. Thanks